# Cannot get bash variable changed in sourced script after pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I constructed a simple example to illustrate the problem:

`caller.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
state="loaded"
source "sh/callee.sh" 2>&1
echo "$state"
```

`callee.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
state="integrated"
```

when I run `caller.sh`, it gives the result I want:

```
integrated
```

But if I add a pipe after the source command:

`caller.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
state="loaded"
source "sh/callee.sh" 2>&1 | cat
echo "$state"
```

The result becomes:

```
loaded
```

**Question:** How can I preserve/retrieve the changed value of `$state` in `caller.sh`?

Comment: pipe-line forks a sub-shell, the value is lost, once the sub shell terminates

Comment: What is your intention using `cat` in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a pipe. The `source` command runs in a subshell that exits after the pipe completes, so `state` is never set in the shell that calls `echo "$state"`. You can use process substitution to "invert" the pipeline:

```
state="loaded"
source "sh/callee.sh" 2>&1 > >(cat)
echo "$state"
```

Now `source` executes in the same shell.

Comment: But why is `cat` needed at all here?

Comment: what does the first `>` do?

Comment: `cat` is just something I came up with in this example. In my program I want to direct stdin and stderr to a log file